# Passing realm object to an pending intent of alarm manager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, realm

I am developing an alarm app and I am trying to pass the realm object to alarm manager for setting an alarm

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = io.realm.AlarmRealmProxy)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1527)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
>                                                                                  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
>                                                                                  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8687)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1307)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:4653)
>                                                                                  at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:562)
>                                                                                  at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:545)
>                                                                                  at in.kka.physiotherapy.model.Alarm.schedule(Alarm.java:143)
>                                                                                  at in.kka.physiotherapy.service.AlarmService.onStartCommand(AlarmService.java:99)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3326)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1582) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>                                                                               Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: io.realm.AlarmRealmProxy$AlarmColumnInfo
>                                                                                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
>                                                                                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
>                                                                                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
>                                                                                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
>                                                                                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
>                                                                                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1522)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764) 
>                                                                                  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8687) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1307) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:4653) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:562) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:545) 
>                                                                                  at in.kka.physiotherapy.model.Alarm.schedule(Alarm.java:143) 
>                                                                                  at in.kka.physiotherapy.service.AlarmService.onStartCommand(AlarmService.java:99) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3326) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1582) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Here is my code my class implements Serializable but i'm not able to pass intent extra, i am getting error here **myIntent.putExtra("alarm", this);**

```
public void schedule(Context context) {
        Realm  realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                setAlarmActive(true);
            }
        });


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmServiceBroadcastReciever.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("alarm", this);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getAlarmTime().getTime(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass a **managed**, "live" realm object, which is based by a proxy implementation - you need to pass a "detached" **unmanaged** object to the intent. Change this line:

```
myIntent.putExtra("alarm", this);
```

To this:

```
myIntent.putExtra("alarm", realm.copyFromRealm(this));
```

Also, you should close the `Realm` instance, preferably wrapping the transaction and `copyFromRealm` call in a `try-catch` block:

```
Realm realm = null;
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm transactionRealm) {
            setAlarmActive(true);
        }
    });
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmServiceBroadcastReciever.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("alarm", realm.copyFromRealm(this));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getAlarmTime().getTime(), pendingIntent);
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @KrishnaBN cool, also check the edited answer about closing realm instance

Comment: You shouldn't pass objects at all. Pass the object id instead and fetch it from realm in the service

Comment: @TimCastelijns not necessarily. Care to elaborate why you shouldn't send an unmanaged snapshot object 'at all'? There are cases for this.

Comment: 1) the object is no longer managed, you lose the advantages of realm 2) if the object is too big, it will crash on newer versions due to intent data limit

Comment: @TimCastelijns so you've pointed out possible cases where it's more convenient to send ID and requery, not why you shouldn't pass objects at all. How about sending objects that don't have a `@PrimaryKey`? What if you **want** a snapshot, so the state of the objects is guaranteed **not** to be different when it's requeried?

Comment: @TimCastelijns that's not true, primary keys are not obligatory.